# How to have a stop value to the sequence generated by SEQUENCE() function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to generate a descending sequence in **Google Sheets**.
But I want that sequence to be dynamically based on another cell's value. So this sequence should be going from that number and stop when it reaches 0.
I was able to set the step value as -1 to get the descending sequence but it is not stopping at 0.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your current formula? What is your input and output? Show some sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
=SEQUENCE(A1+1,1,A1,-1)
```

To omit the `0` values try:

```
=SEQUENCE(A1,1,A1,-1)
```

[image]